# How do I remove objects inside the blast radius?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I set up an explosion in a unit, but I cannot remove objects within the radius of the explosion. How to write the Destroy function in the block for defining objects inside the radius so that these objects are deleted?

```
public void Explode()
{
      Collider[] overlappedColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, Radius);

      for(int i = 0; i < overlappedColliders.Length; i++)
      {
          Rigidbody rigidbody = overlappedColliders[i].attachedRigidbody;
          if(rigidbody)
          {
              rigidbody.AddExplosionForce(Force, transform.position, Radius, 1f);

              Explosion explosion = rigidbody.GetComponent<Explosion>();
              if(!explosion)
              {
                  if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, rigidbody.position) < Radius)
                  {
                      Destroy(explosion.gameObject);
                  }
              }
          }
    }

 }

 public void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision)
 {
     if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Explosion")
     {
         Explode();
         Destroy(gameObject);
         Instantiate(ExplosionEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
     }
 }

 private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
 {
      Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
      Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, Radius);
 }
```

Comment: So hat exactly is not working as expected with the code you have? is the condition `if(!explosion)` fulfilled?

Comment: Just in general you should first do `Instantiate(ExplosionEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);` and then `Destroy(gameObject);` otherwise you are trying to access a position of something that doesn't exist anymore ...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, in my opinion, make a gameobject that contains elements that is in the radius of the explosion, when the explosion happens you can destroy it immediately by referencing to that gameobject and destroy it

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
public void Explode()
{

    //I left this part of your script since it adds a push effect to the objects caught in the explosion
    Collider[] overlappedColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, Radius);

    for(int i = 0; i < overlappedColliders.Length; i++)
    {
        Rigidbody rigidbody = overlappedColliders[i].attachedRigidbody;

        if(rigidbody)
        {
            rigidbody.AddExplosionForce(Force, transform.position, Radius, 1f);
        }
    }
    
    //Now destroy the objects in the blast radius applying a delay based in distance
    var detonationPoint = transform.position;

    //filter the objects in the scene by distance and ignore the source gameobject
    var objectsInExplosionRadius = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>().Select(x => new
    {
        distance = Vector3.Distance(x.transform.position, detonationPoint),
        obj = x
    }).Where(x => x.distance <= Radius && !ReferenceEquals(x, gameObject));

    foreach (var objectInRadius in objectsInExplosionRadius)
    {
        //apply the destruction delay as desired
        Destroy(objectInRadius.obj, objectInRadius.distance);
    }
}
```